# When is the sum of integrals the integral of the sums?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The following exercise is the root of my question. I'm not that familiar with how to type out mathematics so please bear with me.

Exercise: Prove that if a series $\sum^\infty_{j=1} f_j(x)$ of integrable functions on an interval $[a,b]$ is uniformly convergent on $[a,b]$, then the sum function $f$ is integrable and 
$\int_a^{b} f(x) \,dx = \sum^\infty_{j=1} \int_a^{b}f_j(x) \,dx$.

If we let $s_k(x)=\sum^k_{j=1} f_j(x)$, then we have a sequence uniformly converging to $f$. There is a theorem in the textbook I use which I think can be used to show that $f$ is integrable because each $f_j$ is integrable. Furthermore, I can say that $\lim_{k \to \infty} (\int_a^{b} s_k(x)\,dx) = \int_a^{b}f(x)\,dx$.

However, this is not quite what we want. We have an integral of the sums equal to the integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$. We would like the sum of the integrals of $f_j$ over $[a,b]$ to be equal to the integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$. When, if ever would the sum of the integrals equal the integral of the sums? If there is a theorem for this, please give a proof or direct me to one. Or, if I'm approaching this incorrectly, could you point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: For finite sums - such as $s_k$ - you can always interchange summation and integration.

Comment: You have the answer! All you need to do is to bring the **finite** sum in the integral $\int_{a}^{b} s_k $ outside the integral sign. This is allowed for finite sums by the linearity of the integral operator.

Comment: Thanks to both of you very much!